# How to write Dictionary contents to a textfile

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have declared a dictionary like below--

```
Dictionary<int, string> dic = new Dictionary<int, string>()
{
       {977,"String1"}, 
       {1021,"String2"},
       {784,"String3"},
       {801, "String4"}
};
```

In my textfile value will be contain like this-

```
977,"String1", 
1021,"String2",
784,"String3",
801, "String4"
```

I want to store above dictionary keys and values manually in a text file and want to access like dictionary by for loop.

Like this--

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> pair in dic)
{
      if (pair.Key == any_integer_value_to_compare)
      {
           Console.WriteLine(pair.Value);
      }
}
```

How can I do that??

Comment: Well which bit is causing you problems? The file part or the loop part? They seem unrelated...

Comment: Actually file part is not problem. But how can I access those value from file this is my problem. #Jon Skeet

Comment: I have showed the dictionary for clearance.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by that. We don't know what's the file looks like, or what reading from the file has to do with the loop in the second part of your question. This question is *very* unclear. Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Comment: You need some kind of serialization. You need to decide what serialization you prefer (CSV? JSON? Something else?) and then write/read the file accordingly.

Comment: #Jon Skeet, I have edited my question. In textfile there are two parts (int) (string). Now How can I access them from my program. I think you are clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use serialization/De-serialization to store and retrieve dictionary data from a XML file. It's better method as far as performance is concerned.

Here is how you can implement that:

**Declare class Item:**

```
public class item
{
  [XmlAttribute]
  public int id;

  [XmlAttribute]
  public string value;
}
```

**Your Dictionary:**

```
Dictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>()
{
   {977,"String1"}, 
   {1021,"String2"},
   {784,"String3"},
   {801, "String4"}
};
```

**Create Serializer object:**

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(item[]),newXmlRootAttribute() { ElementName = "items" });
```

**Serialization:**

```
serializer.Serialize(stream,dict.Select(kv=>new item(){id = kv.Key,value=kv.Value}).ToArray() );
```

**Deserialization:**

```
var myDict = ((item[])serializer.Deserialize(stream)).ToDictionary(i =>i.id, i => i.value);
```

**Accessing your dictionary values**

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> pair in myDict )
{
  if (pair.Key == any_integer_value_to_compare)
   {
     Console.WriteLine(pair.Value);
   }
}
```

In this way you can systematically store the state of your dictionary values at the particular instance and access it later on by de-serializing the XML file.

Comment: What's ```newXmlRootAttribute```? Also "'XmlSerializer' does not contain a definition for 'ElementName'".

Answer (score 0):

To create or override a CSV file (note: there're *no spaces and quotes*)

```
  977,String1
  1021,String2
  784,String3
  801,String4
```

you can use Linq

```
File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\MyTest\MyFile.txt", dic
  .Select(pair => String.Join(",", pair.Key, pair.Value)));
```

If you want to add quotations for values, add them (the simplest implementation)

```
File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\MyTest\MyFile.txt", dic
  .Select(pair => String.Join(",", pair.Key, "\"" + pair.Value + "\"")));
```

you can't add spaces since line

```
  {801, "String4"},
```

is totally equals to

```
  {801,"String4"},
```

In case you want to convert the dictionary into `String` (and then combine it 
with some other text(s) in order ro put into text file):

```
String text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, dic
  .Select(pair => String.Join(",", pair.Key, pair.Value))
```